# How to render single field from firestore document with React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, rendering

for our university project (4th semester) we are building a quiz app in React using MaterialUI for styling and Firestore as DB.

I'm currently seriously struggling with just displaying/rendering data from a firestore document.

The firestore collection is called user and every user that signs up gets a document with his/her email as ID. As fields we will use name, surname, email and subject, but currently only email is populated.

On our profile page we now want to display said user data (email for now), but when loading the app, the element is left blank.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "../App.css";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import {
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  Container,
  Card,
  CardContent,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { PageTitle } from "../components/common";
import { db , auth} from "../firebase";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
createStyles({
  proflileCard: {
      minWidth: 200,
  },
  spaceLG: {
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(30)
  },
  spaceXL: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(10),
  },
})
);


function Profile() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const user = auth.currentUser
  const userEmail = user.email
  const userRef = db.collection('user')
  
  
  function displayMail(){

   
    userRef.where("email", "==" , userEmail).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().email);
        const data = doc.data()
        const mail = data.email  

        return mail
        
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Fehler beim Abrufen des Dokuments", error)
    })  
  }
  
  return (
    < >
        <PageTitle title="Profil" />
    
        <Card 
        className={classes.profileCard} 
        variant='outlined'>
          <CardContent>

              <Typography 
            className={classes.spaceLG} 
            variant='h5'> 
              {displayMail()}
            </Typography> 
           
            
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
         
    </>
    
  );
}
```

Is there a React or firestore functionality that I'm missing?

Thanks for looking at our mess :)

## Update

I could fix this after talking to a friend and reading through the useState and useEffect explanations.
I switched from a function to useEffect and replaced querySnapshot with a simple documentSnapshot.

This got it working:

```
function Profile() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const user = auth.currentUser
  const userEmail = user.email
  const userRef = db.collection('user').doc(userEmail)
  const [mail, setMail] = useState('')    
  
  useEffect(() => {

    
    userRef.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {

      try {
        console.log(docSnapshot.id, " => ", docSnapshot.data().email);
        const data = docSnapshot.data()
        const mail = data.email 

        setMail(mail)
        
      } catch(error) {
          console.log("Fehler beim Abrufen des Dokuments", error)
        } 
    })    

  }, [])
  
  
  return (
    <div>
        <PageTitle title="Profil" />
    
        <Card 
        className={classes.profileCard} 
        variant='outlined'
        >
          <CardContent>

              <Typography 
            className={classes.spaceLG}
            variant='h5' 
            > 
              Login-Data
            </Typography> 
            <Typography>
              <strong>E-Mail: </strong>{mail}
            </Typography>
       //[...]
       </div>
         
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the Firebase SDK as if it is synchronous. You need to take care of the `async` nature of it and idealy use `state` to handle that. Your code could look like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../App.css";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import {
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  Container,
  Card,
  CardContent,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { PageTitle } from "../components/common";
import { db, auth } from "../firebase";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    proflileCard: {
      minWidth: 200,
    },
    spaceLG: {
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(30),
    },
    spaceXL: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(10),
    },
  })
);

function Profile() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [mails,setMails] = useState([]);
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const userEmail = user.email;
  const userRef = db.collection("user");

  function displayMail() {
    userRef
      .where("email", "==", userEmail)
      .get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        const tempMails=[]
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().email);
          const data = doc.data();
          const mail = data.email;
          tempMails.push(mail);

          
        });
        setMails(tempMails);

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Fehler beim Abrufen des Dokuments", error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle title="Profil" />

      <Card className={classes.profileCard} variant="outlined">
        <CardContent>
          <Typography className={classes.spaceLG} variant="h5">
            {mails.map(m=>{
              return <div>{m}</div>)})}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this using useState and useEffect. I also switched from querysnapshot to documentSnapshot.

Comment: Great to hear that. It would be nice if you would mark the answe as accepted.